# how install python3.4 psycopg2 in centos pyvenv

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, centos6

i install python 3.4 in my centos 6.5
i follow this tutorial

http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

so i do not change the system defaule python 2.6.6

and i use python3.4 pyvenv create a project folder for my django website
now i need install postgresql database,so i try install psycopg2.
in that pyvenv ,the python version is 3.4

when i pip install psycopg2,it show the error

```
Downloading psycopg2-2.5.2.tar.gz (685kB): 685kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/mysns/build/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Error: pg_config executable not found.



Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH

or specify the full executable path with the option:



    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...



or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /mysns/build/psycopg2
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

then i do a little search ,someone say i need install other lib
i need do this

yum install libpqxx-devel python-devel

every thing install complete
 however ,then i install psycopg2,
pip install psycopg2,
it still show the same error
then i notice ,the previous lib ,only intall python-devel-2.6.6 
this is the default system python version
even i try

yum python3-devel,

it do not install python3.4 devel lib to my python3.4 pyvenv folder

how can i fix the problem? can i install python3.4 devel lib in this pyvenv folder?

Comment: The error says pg_config not found, right? Is PostgreSQL installed? What do you get if you execute which pg_config?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i had a look around and I found out the following package that made it work:

```
wget https://forensics.cert.org/cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh cert-forensics-tools-release*rpm
sudo yum --enablerepo=forensics install python3-psycopg2
```

also I found that there is a package called python33-python-psycopg2 that could help you out but I did not try it so take it as a shaky chance more than a way to go, anyway http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/06/24/using-rhscl-django-on-python-3-with-postgresql/ you can find the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
python3.4 -m pip install psycopg2
```